# get voted EOS per producers

Tags: voting

I'm trying to get EOS amounts which used for voting.

In jungle mainnet monitor (http://eosnetworkmonitor.io), it shows number of votes per bps.

Also, I found table in eosio.system contract which name is "producers". It contains "votes_total", but it is calculated values (with stake2vote function in voting.cpp file) so It didn't represent EOS.

Is there any method to get acquired EOS by bps?

Comment: You can check any user's account and EOS amount through blockchain explorer. You can check BP's general info https://eospark.com/MainNet/bp/starteosiobp and amount of EOS he has by viewing his account: https://eospark.com/MainNet/account/starteosiobp

Comment: The answer here https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/how-to-get-bp-votes-in-eos-using-cleos/1737#1737 is not clear either.