# How to get BP votes in EOS using cleos?

Tags: cleos, block-producer, voting

```
cleos system listproducers -l 21 -j
{
  "rows": [{
  "owner": "bitfinexeos1",
  "total_votes": "322468184386323200.00000000000000000",
  "producer_key": "EOS6sgKjHUFtY1XxxQaMDwfxBac6nDBibVzZHb8LFMVmvSjcCdDhE",
  "is_active": 1,
  "url": "https://www.bitfinex.com",
  "unpaid_blocks": 5884,
  "last_claim_time": "1532192253500000",
  "location": 0
},
```

total_votes is a very strange number. How to get votes in EOS?

Answer (score 1):

The votes is not the EOS amount, each EOS has a weight with time change, the half-decayed time is one year, the weight of one EOS is 2^(current year(2018)+（days since the year/365） - 2000), and you must multi 10000 because EOS has 4 decimals

Also take care that one account can vote to 30 nodes.